# VBA issue finding string in a string array when in fact it is a part of the array

Tags: arrays, vba, string

I am confused about this case I came across.
I Have a code:

```
Sub Testing()

Dim UnitArray
UnitArray = Array("Standard", "Jumbo")

Dim Unit As String
Unit = "Standard"

If IsInArray(UnitArray, Unit) Then
MsgBox ("Great success")
End If

End Sub
```

And a function:

```
Function IsInArray(arr As Variant, myVal As Variant) As Boolean

   Dim mtch
   mtch = Application.Match(myVal, arr, True)
   If Not IsError(mtch) Then
     If mtch = UBound(arr) Then
        If arr(UBound(arr)) = myVal Then IsInArray = True: Exit Function
     Else
        IsInArray = True: Exit Function
     End If
   End If
   IsInArray = False
   
End Function
```

If that array has only "Standard" - it works, but else it doesn't find the value.
What's the mistake I have made?

Comment: I cannot understand your question, sorry. You posted a function I supplied to another question placed by you. Now, how do you test it for the second initial array element? Did you try `If IsInArray(UnitArray, "Jumbo") Then` and it does not return `True`? "I am confused" does not let us understand what confusion are you talking about... What did you try, what were your expectations against the return?

Comment: @FaneDuru - the problem is that currently `If mtch = UBound(arr) Then` is `True` because `arr` is 0-based but `Match` is 1-based. So it appears that `"Standard"` is not in the array. But really, this function is overkill for what OP wants to do.

Comment: Also `Match` is much slower than looping the array elements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754096/matching-values-in-string-array

Comment: The above function has been designed to work for `Integers`, if I remember well. Only in such a case `Match` may return the last array element **if not a match**. For strings, it should return a match, even if the array is 1D or 2D type...

Comment: @FaneDuru - I guess OP is looking for exact match too. `mtch = Application.Match(myVal, arr, 0)` probably.

Comment: @BigBen That's why I asked him to better describe his 'confusion'... You may be right, I agree, but this looks something subliminal for me.  Like you know, English is not my strong point... :) `IsInArray` does exactly what its name suggests. It only returns `True` if a match exist. I will post a simpler piece of code able to deal with strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test a strings array in a even simpler way. The function you try using has been designed for `Integers` array...

```
Sub Testing()
Dim UnitArray
UnitArray = Array("Standard", "Jumbo")

Dim Unit As String
Unit = "Standard"
Dim mtch
'mtch = Application.match(Unit, UnitArray, 0)
mtch = Application.match("Jumbo", UnitArray, 0)
If Not IsError(mtch) Then
    MsgBox ("Great success")
End If
```

Like you can see, it correctly returns for any array element... Commenting/uncommenting the code lines starting with `mtch` will return a match for any of the array elements.